# Toggle class on <body> with button click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a button, when clicked I would like the body to get the class "open-menu". With jQuery it was very easy, all I had to do what was add this line of code

```js
$('.burger').click(function() { $('body').toggleClass('menu-open'); }); };
```

But I don't understand how I can achieve that in Angular with typescript! All the info I can find online pertains to toggling a class on the same element!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a boolean property to your Component Class:

```
menuOpened: boolean = false;
```

Once the button is clicked, you need to do two things:

1. Toggle the `menuOpened`:

   ```
   <button (click)="menuOpened = !menuOpened">Click to Toggle Menu</button>
   ```
2. Add the class conditionally:

   ```
   <div [class.menu-open]="menuOpened"></div>
   ```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/toggle-class-on-button-click?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

goes without angular simply: `document.body.classList.add('menu-open');`
to remove: `document.body.classList.remove('menu-open')`

Comment: Angular doesn't recommend interacting with `document` like this. Consider using `@ViewChild` if that's how you want to suggest doing it.

Comment: use in constructor: @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,